# How to call a test case in Selenium rc with PHP?

Tags: phpunit, selenium-rc

can you tell me how to run a test case in selenium RC with php?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the official guide at http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/selenium.html

Create a class that extends from PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase which will contain the methods from PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and the selenium specific methods:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php';

class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->setBrowser('*firefox');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com/');
    }

    public function testTitle()
    {
        $this->open('http://www.example.com/');
        $this->assertTitle('Example WWW Page');
    }
}
?>
```

Then browse in your console to where this file is saved and run: phpunit filename.php

If you want to run an specific test you could use the --filter options as well.

Hope this helps.